# Are meta and stack-overflow hosted on different machines?

Tags: support, specific-question, behavior, server, subdomains

Are meta and stack-overflow hosted on different machines?

I ask because, I can't get to stackoverflow.com, but I can get to meta.stackoverflow.com (obviously). My ISP has been particularly crappy with some domains lately, and indeed with some folders of some websites, while the root of the domain loads fine. In this case, I can load your sub-domain, but not your root domain.

I'm starting to think this is my ISP, and I'm trying to rule things out.

Could it be, that one of the root hosts like level3 is not play nice with my ISP?
(Kinda like what happend back a few years ago, where they stoped supporting each other traffic, cutting off some websites from their users.)

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>tracert meta.stackoverflow.com

Tracing route to meta.stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.215]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    12 ms     9 ms    12 ms  ool-18bf1001.dyn.optonline.net [24.191.16.1]
  2    11 ms     9 ms     9 ms  64.15.5.1
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    10 ms     9 ms     9 ms  64.15.5.97
  5    10 ms    18 ms   105 ms  rtr4-tg10-1.in.nycmny83.cv.net [64.15.0.17]
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7    13 ms    12 ms    11 ms  te0-0-0-4.ccr21.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.0.53]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9   100 ms    52 ms    52 ms  multi-use.cogentco.com [154.54.25.81]
 10    82 ms    73 ms   128 ms  te4-4.mpd02.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.130]
 11    89 ms    91 ms    87 ms  te7-3.ccr01.smf01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.14]
 12   100 ms    98 ms    98 ms  te4-1.ccr01.pdx01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.94]
 13   104 ms   102 ms   102 ms  38.104.104.98
 14   100 ms    97 ms   100 ms  vl-12-PTLDORPBCR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.21]
 15   105 ms   161 ms   108 ms  vl16-eugnor53cr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.190]
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17   106 ms   103 ms   103 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19   104 ms   105 ms   104 ms  peak-colo-196-215.peak.org [69.59.196.215]

Trace complete.

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>tracert stackoverflow.com

Tracing route to stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    10 ms     9 ms    12 ms  ool-18bf1001.dyn.optonline.net [24.191.16.1]
  2     9 ms     9 ms    10 ms  64.15.5.2
  3    11 ms     9 ms     9 ms  64.15.10.129
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  rtr3-tg11-2.wan.hcvlny.cv.net [64.15.4.1]
  6   217 ms    89 ms    13 ms  64.15.0.149
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    12 ms    11 ms    11 ms  te0-1-0-5.ccr21.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.2.85]
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11    64 ms    67 ms    65 ms  te4-4.mpd02.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.130]
 12    91 ms    92 ms    87 ms  te7-3.ccr01.smf01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.14]
 13    99 ms    99 ms   101 ms  te4-1.ccr01.pdx01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.94]
 14   103 ms   101 ms    99 ms  38.104.104.98
 15   101 ms   100 ms   101 ms  PTLDORPBCR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.209]
 16   106 ms   102 ms   105 ms  vl16-eugnor53cr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.190]
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18   109 ms   105 ms   117 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [66.249.90.104]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    13 ms    13 ms    14 ms  ool-18bf1001.dyn.optonline.net [24.191.16.1]
  2     9 ms    10 ms     8 ms  64.15.5.2
  3    10 ms    12 ms     9 ms  64.15.10.129
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5   532 ms    13 ms    16 ms  rtr3-tg11-2.wan.hcvlny.cv.net [64.15.4.1]
  6    10 ms    11 ms    10 ms  64.15.0.198
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    14 ms    10 ms     9 ms  72.14.238.232
  9    11 ms    12 ms    11 ms  209.85.241.222
 10    11 ms    11 ms     9 ms  lga15s04-in-f104.1e100.net [66.249.90.104]

Trace complete.

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>ping sstatic.net

Pinging sstatic.net [69.59.196.213] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 69.59.196.213: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=45
Reply from 69.59.196.213: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=45
Reply from 69.59.196.213: bytes=32 time=107ms TTL=45
Reply from 69.59.196.213: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=45

Ping statistics for 69.59.196.213:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 104ms, Maximum = 108ms, Average = 106ms

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>tracert sstatic.net

Tracing route to sstatic.net [69.59.196.213]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    10 ms     9 ms     7 ms  ool-18bf1001.dyn.optonline.net [24.191.16.1]
  2     9 ms    12 ms     9 ms  64.15.5.2
  3     9 ms     9 ms    12 ms  64.15.10.129
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    13 ms    12 ms     9 ms  64.15.5.97
  6    14 ms    15 ms    25 ms  rtr4-tg10-1.in.nycmny83.cv.net [64.15.0.17]
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    12 ms    12 ms    11 ms  te0-3-0-5.ccr21.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.6.45]
  9    39 ms    41 ms    38 ms  te3-3.ccr01.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.29.153]
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11    64 ms    63 ms    64 ms  te4-4.mpd02.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.130]
 12    87 ms    91 ms    87 ms  te7-3.ccr01.smf01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.14]
 13    99 ms   101 ms   104 ms  te4-1.ccr01.pdx01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.94]
 14   102 ms    99 ms    99 ms  38.104.104.98
 15    99 ms    99 ms   101 ms  vl-12-PTLDORPBCR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.21]
 16   102 ms   103 ms   103 ms  vl16-eugnor53cr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.190]
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18   104 ms   104 ms   106 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20   107 ms   105 ms   106 ms  sstatic.net [69.59.196.213]

Trace complete.

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>tracert xkcd.com

Tracing route to xkcd.com [72.26.203.98]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     9 ms    11 ms    10 ms  ool-18bf1001.dyn.optonline.net [24.191.16.1]
  2    12 ms    13 ms    11 ms  64.15.5.2
  3    13 ms    10 ms     9 ms  64.15.10.129
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    19 ms    10 ms    10 ms  rtr4-tg11-2.wan.hcvlny.cv.net [64.15.4.25]
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    12 ms    12 ms     9 ms  0.ae59.tsr1.lga5.us.voxel.net [208.122.44.202]
  9    11 ms    14 ms    12 ms  0.ae57.csr2.lga6.us.voxel.net [208.122.44.210]
 10    14 ms    12 ms    12 ms  72.26.203.98

Trace complete.
```

Funny, when I first tried to post this, it did not work from the location at the time.
This was due to api.recaptcha.net failing to load and the captcha would not show up.
Here is the ping and tracert for that mess:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>ping api.recaptcha.net

Pinging api.recaptcha.net [69.12.97.165] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 69.12.97.165:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tomlin>tracert api.recaptcha.net

Tracing route to api.recaptcha.net [69.12.97.165]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    12 ms     8 ms    10 ms  ool-18bf1001.dyn.optonline.net [24.191.16.1]
  2    10 ms     8 ms     9 ms  64.15.5.2
  3    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  64.15.10.129
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5   627 ms    19 ms    12 ms  rtr4-tg11-2.wan.hcvlny.cv.net [64.15.4.25]
  6    23 ms    14 ms    10 ms  rtr4-tg10-1.in.nycmny83.cv.net [64.15.0.17]
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    12 ms    14 ms    11 ms  ae-31-89.car1.NewYork1.Level3.net [4.68.16.131]
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Must be a slow day for so few visitors: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXmv8quf_xM

Comment: @random That guy is an idiot.....

Comment: @random Thanks for that video I feel so much smarter now I will become an elite hacker!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39807/stack-overflow-network-load-balancer-architecture) question.

Answer (score 2):

The web servers are different, but they talk to the same database and are behind the same load balancer.

Comment: You sure? I thought SO was the only site with a load balancer and that Meta was on a separate machine.